# How to extract data from a string with specific start and end position using Php?

Tags: php

I have a code which helps to retrieve line from a text file based on the selected value. I want it to only return a specific part of the string starting at position 166 and ending at 177 instead of the whole line. How can I achieve that, can someone please help me.

Php code:

```
<?php
$file = 'masterfile.out';
$searchfor = '125302532569';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

// search, and store all matching occurrences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);

}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, replace this statement: `echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);`

with this:

```
echo substr(implode("\n", $matches[0]),166,11);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `substr()`:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
$partOfContent = substr($contents, 166, 11);
```

Comment: I added the line to the code; but, it is returning the substr from line 1 not from the row where we had the match based on the selected search for value.

Comment: please kindly help

Comment: as, you are using an array. You need to put the implode statement within the substr statement.